# Example environment for IEEE

Tags: ieeetran

I need an example in a paper for an IEEE workshop. There is no example environment in the template. How should I set it up?

The document class is `\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}`.

Comment: *An* example? Why do you need to go through the trouble of setting up an container for a one-time use? Just use `\textbf{Example:}`, maybe?

Comment: I would like it to be clear where the example ends so I thought something else might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\begin{document}
\begin{example}
  This is an example.
\end{example}
\end{document}
```

[image]